# Can I load a third-party .dll in R?

Tags: c, r, dll

I am running Windows 7, and I know the DLL was built using Visual Studio C++ 2010. Since I don't have the source code I can't build it on-the-fly in R when creating a package (NAMESPACE). **At this stage, I don't need to create a package**, I just want to load the library in R using `dyn.load()`. Since it is a dll I suppose it is portable to any client program, but I would just make sure, because I know that it was not compiled using `GNU gcc`.

**EDIT:**

I want to call all the functions that the dll deploys.

Comment: You don't know anything about the DLL. I am not sure that `dyn.load` will work here since R looks for the symbol named `R_init_mylib`...Honestly I don't see what do you have tried before asking this question.

Comment: Do you want to call any functions, or do you just want to load the DLL?

Comment: I know that it has SEXP as input and output of the functions, so I can call the functions, after I load the .dll, using .Call. There is one version that uses .C and you pass native C types together with a pointer to the output.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to call the functions that the dll deploys...

Comment: The question says nothing about that. You simply ask if you can load the DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, agreed. I just edited the post. thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, R can load it using `dyn.load`. You may or may not be able to actually call the functions it exports, though. Unless the functions' arguments correspond to what R can handle, they won't be usable. If this is the case, you can write a wrapper dll that acts as a translation layer between it and R.

Comment: The dll uses SEXP input and output parameters...In this case will I be able to access the functions, even if I haven't compiled and linked it using CMD R SHLIB or any GNU compiler?