# Importing .NET DLL to Python or R

Tags: python, r, matlab, dll, dllimport

I have a .NET DLL and a sample code in Matlab, which uses this DLL and works.
The Matlab code which imports the DLL is

```
    function ReaderLib = ReaderInitialize(dllPath)
          netObj = NET.addAssembly(dllPath);
          ReaderLib =  System.Activator.CreateInstance(netObj.AssemblyHandle.GetType('lib.ReaderDotNet'));
    end
```

This function returns the object which exposes all functions of the DLL.

I need to use this DLL in existing Python and/or R code, but I was not able to make it work.

In Python I tried

```
    import ctypes
    DllObj = ctypes.WinDLL (dllPath)
```

In R I tried

```
DllObj <- dyn.load(dllPath)
```

In both cases I obtain more or less empty objects, so I assume I am not doing it right. What is the correct way to import this DLL in Python and/or R?

Comment: Have you considered this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723321/can-i-load-a-third-party-dll-in-r

Comment: I understand that R have specific requirements for how DLL should be built, so it may not be possible to import this DLL into R. What about Python? Is there a similar functionality in Python as in the Matlab example?

Comment: What do you mean by "*more or less empty objects*" ?

Comment: I am getting objects that only have some metadata like the name of the DLL and few other values, but there are no exposed functions.

Comment: R or Python. Please pick one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe it's a long shot for this to work in R, so I guess Python... :)